# Uncontrolled scattering while animating blender particles

Tags: particles

I defined particles to represent granules. It worked fine in preview but after extracting rendered output (video), the particles scatter randomly. How do i fix this? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Add your . blend file.

Comment: can you try to be more clear? your problem isn't clear by the question. Press the edit button and change it